# How to remove computers in bulk from AD on Windows Server 2008

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008

I have a list of computers (CSV) I need to remove from AD on an old Windows Server 2008. Powershell doesn't support the command

`Get-Module ActiveDirectory`

What is the best way to do this without removing one by one?

Comment: Server 2008 **does** support the `ActiveDirectory` module, but you need to install it from Add Features. It's named either "Active Directory Domain Controller Tools" in Server 2008, or "AD DS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools" in 2008 R2. See the answer here for detailed steps: https://serverfault.com/a/109183/411612 or use the quest AD powershell tools instead